# How does one get all query params from within a endpoint?

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I'm writing a toy finch project and trying to allow requests to specify arbitrary query parameters to set some value. I am able to retrieve the value for a known parameter name (i.e. `param[String]("foo")`) but how can I get a `Map[String,String]` of all the query parameters?

i.e. hit `/myendpoint?foo=bar&baz=baq` and within the response handler be able to access the value `Map("foo"->"bar", "baz"->"baq")`

I looked in the docs and there seems to be some way to access all the headers but no equivalent functionality is given for accessing params.